# How to delete a csv header in python?

Tags: python, csv

I've got a huge csv file (around 10GB of data) and I want to delete its header.

Searching on this web I found this solution:

```
with open("test.csv",'r') as f, open("updated_test.csv",'w') as f1:
next(f) # skip header line
for line in f:
    f1.write(line)
```

But this would imply creating a new csv file. ¿Is there a way just to delete the header without looping over all the csv lines?

Comment: why are you making a copy of a 10 GB file line by line? remove the header and store it with a new name.....!!!

Comment: Why use python? `sed` can do that pretty easily. If you really want to use Python and csv, you'd ideally use Pandas depending on your needs

Comment: with simple `sed -i '1d' test.csv`

Comment: I don't think you can remove a specific line "in-place" with python. You can only overwrite the whole file, and that means loading the content in memory.

Comment: Does `sed -i` really just reset the starting location of the file?  Or, does it essentially copy the entire file in place with the first line "moved up" to the start of the file (not creating any substantial savings in processing over the OP's solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point you've got is this:  You want to delete a line in the beginning of a file.  Straight forward this means you need to shift the complete contents *after* the header to the front which in turn means copying the whole file.

But this is way too costly of course when we are talking about 10GB files.

In your case I propose to read the first two lines, store their sizes, open the file for reading/writing without creating (so no truncation takes place), write the second(!) line at the beginning of the file and pad it with as many spaces as are necessary to overwrite the original first and second line.

This way you overwrite the first two lines with a very long line which semantically only contains the data from the second line (the first data line) and syntactically contains just some additional trailing spaces (which in CSV files do not hurt normally).

```
with open('a', 'rw+') as f:
  headers = f.readline()
  firstData = f.readline()
  f.seek(0)
  firstData = firstData[:-1] + ' ' * len(headers) + '\n'
  f.write(firstData)
```

My input, spaces displayed as dots here:

```
one.two.three.four.five
1.2.3.4.5
6.7.8.9.10
```

My output, spaces displayed as dots here:

```
1.2.3.4.5........................
6.7.8.9.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas with the header=0

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', sep='joursep', header=0)
```

Comment: i think the OP is trying to avoid loading all 10 GB into memory.

Comment: also, you want `skiprows=1`, not `header=0`